# Java safeguards for when UTF-16 doesn't cut it

Tags: java, character-encoding, utf-16

My *understanding* is that Java uses UTF-16 by default (for `String` and `char` and possibly other types) and that UTF-16 is a major superset of most character encodings on the planet (though, I could be wrong). But I need a way to protect my app for when it's reading files that were generated with encodings (I'm not sure if there are many, or none at all) that UTF-16 doesn't support.

So I ask:

1. Is it safe to assume the file is UTF-16 prior to reading it, or, to maximize my chances of not getting NPEs or other malformed input exceptions, should I be using a character encoding detector like JUniversalCharDet or JCharDet or ICU4J to first detect the encoding?
2. Then, when writing to a file, I need to be sure that a characte/byte didn't make it into the in-memory object (the String, the `OutputStream`, whatever) that produces garbage text/characters when written to a string or file. Ideally, I'd like to have some way of making sure that this garbage-producing character gets caught somehow before making it into the file that I am writing. How do I safeguard against this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: UTF16 **is** an encoding.  It can encode **all** Unicode character.  Beware that surrogate pairs are difficult to work with.

Comment: Detecting the encoding of a file without a BOM is not trivial.

Comment: Thanks @SLaks (+1 on both) - I assume though that there are encodings/sets outside of Unicode? What if we're reading a file that was created with one of these non-Unicode encodings? That is really at the heart of my question.

Comment: ...for example, what if we encounter something outside the [`StandardCharsets`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/StandardCharsets.html)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java [normally uses UTF-16 for its internal representation of characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699071/what-is-the-javas-internal-represention-for-string-modified-utf-8-utf-16). n Java `char` arrays are a sequence of UTF-16 encoded Unicode codepoints. By default `char` values are considered to be Big Endian (as any Java basic type is). You should however not use `char` values to write strings to files or memory. You should make use of the character encoding/decoding facilities in the Java API (see below).

UTF-16 is not a major superset of encodings. Actually, UTF-8 and UTF-16 can both encode any Unicode code point. In that sense, Unicode *does* define almost any character that you possibly want to use in modern communication.

If you read a file from disk and asume UTF-16 then you would quickly run into trouble. Most text files are using ASCII or an extension of ASCII to use all 8 bits of a byte. Examples of these extensions are UTF-8 (which can be used to read any ASCII text) or ISO 8859-1 (Latin). Then there are a lot of encodings e.g. used by Windows that are an extension of those extensions. UTF-16 is *not* compatible with ASCII, so it should not be used as default for most applications.

So yes, please use some kind of detector if you want to read a lot of plain text files with unknown encoding. This should answer question #1.

As for question #2, think of a file that is completely ASCII. Now you want to add a character that is not in the ASCII. You choose UTF-8 (which is a pretty safe bet). There is no way of knowing that the program that opens the file guesses correctly guesses that it should use UTF-8. It may try to use Latin or even worse, assume 7-bit ASCII. In that case you get garbage. Unfortunately there are no smart tricks to make sure this never happens.

Look into the [`CharsetEncoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/class-use/CharsetEncoder.html) and [`CharsetDecoder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/charset/class-use/CharsetDecoder.html) classes to see how Java handles encoding/decoding.

Comment: The beginning is misleading, you say _[Java] uses Unicode code points_ (which is correct), but before that you say _Java does not use UTF-16_ (which is wrong). Each `char` represents a Unicode code point, encoded in UTF-16

Comment: Thanks @owlstead (+1) - so there's no way to check that each character (as I write it to file) isn't a valid character in the designated encoding? Nothing like `Character.verifyEncoding(someChar, "UTF-16");`???

Comment: Now it's more worse. You say: "_Java does not use UTF-16 for its internal representation of characters_" whereas you should say "_Java **uses** UTF-16 for its internal representation of characters_"

Comment: See the [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html) It clearly states: **The Java platform uses the UTF-16 representation in char arrays and in the String and StringBuffer classes.**

Comment: @jlordo OK, fixed it best I could without making this into a whole chapter on string encoding, basically as user you just see char's though, which makes the whole point a bit moot. When encoding you want to know how the text looks as bytes, and Java may not represent the characters in memory as you would expect. Not that it matters because you cannot get to the memory representation in the first place.

Comment: That's great guys, I'm glad you both worked it out. But what about my suggestion for verifying each character against a specific encoding?

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys Check the `CharsetDecoder` class first, and see if you understand how it works. That might answer your question.

Comment: So, you mean define event handlers for malformed inputs (for a specific charset); and then, if such an event happens, I know that a bad (unsupported) char got in there somehow? Is that what you mean? Thanks again!

Comment: @DirtyMikeAndTheBoys Yup, that's basically it. Beware that the methods defined for `String` accept invalid characters without so much as a warning, you *should* use `CharsetEncoder` and `CharsetDecoder` for applications that have requirements like your application has.

Comment: Minor note: as UTF-16 uses "units" (may have that term wrong) of 16 bits you can encode it using little endian (UTF-16LE) and big endian. Then you may use a BOM header at the start of the file or not. So just choosing UTF-16 still leaves you with a choice or two.

Comment: @jlordo it was still not up to standards (at least, my standards) so I rewrote the entire first paragraph, if you have remarks please share, thanks for the criticism up to now.

Comment: @owlstead: It has no more wrong information. I don't understand the sentence _char arrays are semantically speaking a form of UTF-16 encoding_. I'd simply put _In Java char arrays are a sequence of UTF-16 encoded Unicode codepoints._

Comment: @jlordo OK, I'll change it to that. I still have the urge to make clear that the internal memory representation may *not* be UTF-16 as it is an implementation detail.

Comment: @owlstead: Apart from memory optimizations in newer Versions of Java and serialized Strings it is UTF-16 internally (in Oracle Java and all other versions I know of). Do you know any exception to that rule?

Comment: @jlordo no, but I would not be surprised if there were a few (possibly in the future). That said, it would probably be a nightmare to rewrite the String if you want to use it with a native library. I'm currently programming Java Card classic, and it certainly encodes strings differently (it doesn't :P) For the asker it doesn't matter much, the internal representation should be out of reach.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever a conversion between bytes and characters takes place, Java allows to specify the character encoding to be used. If it is not specified, a machine dependent default encoding is used. In some encodings the bit pattern representing a certain character has no similarity with the bit pattern used for the same character in UTF-16 encoding.

To question 1 the answer is therefore "no", you cannot assume the file is encoded in UTF-16.

It depends on the used encoding which characters are representable.