# Android cross version new String() or encryption error

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography, aes

I have this test code:

```
byte[] aesPass1 = { (byte) 204, (byte) 204, (byte) 204, (byte) 204, (byte) 204};

encrypted = encryptAES256("Anything".getBytes("UTF8"), new String(aesPass1, "UTF8"), salt, 1000, iv_b);
```

to encrypt some data, and this test code:

```
byte[] aesPass1 = { (byte) 204, (byte) 204, (byte) 204, (byte) 204, (byte) 204};

decryptAES256(encrypted, new String(aesPass1, "UTF8"), salt, 100, iv_b);
```

to decrypt data.

If I encrypt on Android 4.4.4 I can decrypt on the same device (Android 4.4.4) with no problems,
but if I try to decrypt on Android 4.2.2 I get "**pad block corrupted**" error.

Similar, if I encrypt on Android 4.2.2 I can decrypt on the same device (Android 4.2.2) with no problems,
but on Android 4.4.4 I get "**error06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt**" error.

To make this even stranger for me, if I use this code:

```
encrypted = encryptAES256("Anything".getBytes("UTF8"), "pass", salt, 1000, iv_b);
```

to encrypt, and:

```
decryptAES256(encrypted, "pass", salt, 100, iv_b);
```

**everything works fine on both Android 4.2.2 and Android 4.4.4**.

The only difference I can see is using **new String(aesPass1, "UTF8")** fuction.

My encrypt and decrypt functions:

```
public static byte[] encryptAES256(byte[] data, String passphrase, byte[] salt, int iterations, byte[] ivbytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException  {
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    PBEKeySpec specKey = new PBEKeySpec(passphrase.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, 256);
    SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(specKey);
    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(ivbytes));
    return cipher.doFinal(data);
}

public static byte[] decryptAES256(byte[] data, String passphrase, byte[] salt, int iterations, byte[] ivbytes) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException  {
    SecretKeyFactory factory = SecretKeyFactory.getInstance("PBKDF2WithHmacSHA1");
    PBEKeySpec specKey = new PBEKeySpec(passphrase.toCharArray(), salt, iterations, 256);
    SecretKey secretKey = factory.generateSecret(specKey);
    SecretKeySpec secret = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getEncoded(), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret, new IvParameterSpec(ivbytes));
    return cipher.doFinal(data);
}
```

Can you help?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still do not understand Android cross version issue, but I found the source of the problem.

byte[] aesPass1 must have values that can be converted to readable characters by new String(), so:

```
byte[] aesPass1 = { (byte) 204, (byte) 204, (byte) 204, (byte) 204, (byte) 204 };
```

does not work, but:

```
byte[] aesPass1 = { (byte) 65, (byte) 33, (byte) 126, (byte) 77, (byte) 66 };
```

works.

Answer (score 0):

[`BadPaddingException`](http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/crypto/BadPaddingException.html) is what you should expect if the wrong password/key was used during decryption.

> The exception that is thrown when a padding mechanism is expected for the input data, **but the input data does not have the proper padding bytes**.

As I can bet your code has the correct password, the problem must be about `hash` of the `new String()` against declaring it as a `"normalString"` for different devices.

IMO `Android 4.4.4` device must be using a newer version of Java (8) where `String` memory usage has changed as you can see in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31207050/3850595) so hash are differents and passwords checksums does not match.

Comment: But then, is there a way to convert byte[] to String safely? My password must be stored as byte[].

Comment: creating an own object (like `MyHashedString`) with overriden `equals` and `hashcode` can be the sollution for cross versions....

Comment: Also, encrypt and decrypt functions use toCharArray() function on String. How is new String() hash affecting that? BTW, I have no clue how to do what you proposed :)

Comment: I'm not 100% sure this is the problem, no time for me to go deeper, sorry but it smells to me that problem comes from this part...