# Build a bus seats "rows and columns"

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, for-loop, logic

I want to build a Bus seat service. Like:
Seat

```
 1A 1B 1C 1D
 2A 2B 2C 2D
 3A 3B 3C 3D
 3A 3B 3C 3D
 4A 4B 4C 4D 
 5A 5B 5C 5D 
 6A 6B 6C 6D 
 7A 7B 7C 7D
```

Depending of number rows the user want to insert.

My code works well but I would like to improve it. Any suggestion will be so nice. Note: I hate the way I wrote nested for loop with no braces.

code:

```
static void busRow(int numberOfRows){
    String letters[] = {"A","B","C","D"};
    if (numberOfRows<=0){
        System.out.println("Without Seats? It isn't a bus! please insert number of rows");
    }

    for (int i =1; i<=numberOfRows;i++){
        for (int j =0;j<letters.length;j++)
            System.out.print(i+""+letters[j]+" ");
        System.out.println();
    }

}
```

Comment: Are you planning on returning the values of the seats from `busRow` method in the future or just use `println()` to print them in your method?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this belongs on [codereview.se]

Comment: **"Note: I hate the way I wrote nested for loop with no braces"**. If you hate it so much then why in the world did you write it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your nested `for` loop is as efficient as you are going to get as far as the seat generating algorithm.

The only slight change I would suggest is to change your `letters` array from `String[]` to `char[]` assuming that all seat labels are single character letters.  This change is very slight but the reasoning for this is that because a `char` is a primitive data type and only takes up **2 bytes** whereas a `String` is an actual object and, even when empty, requires at least **32 bytes**.

This is a very particular change which won't offer you much a significant change in this example, but its a practice I think that would benefit coding in the future where every byte might count.

Hope this is of some worth!

**Reference:**

[How much memory does a string use in Java 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206851/how-much-memory-does-a-string-use-in-java-8)

Answer (score 2):

The program is relatively simple and well written, there also aren't many changes that can be made to two nested for loops. You've maintained good programming practices with indentation and braces, so there isn't much to improve on!

You could try creating useful functions such as seat reservation or deletion, that could be of use to you. For example, a user wants to sit in seat 2B. You could capture the input from the user and "reserve" the seat with an **X** so your row would then look as follows:

**2A X 2C 2D**

Comment: Well suggested @Gilad. Thanks for your hint.