# Create a large response body for a response entity

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-resttemplate

In order to test and replicate Out of Memory issue on my local system, I'm thinking of creating a huge response body ( in string format)which ideally should exceed the heap memory of JVM.

Is it possible to create a very large string of around  2GB and then assign it to a response entity?

Please help.

Comment: It doesn't need to specifically be in a response body object. You can get this error if any object exceeds the heap space. You should be able to do this with a String

Comment: Check this link for string object size: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206851/how-much-memory-does-a-string-use-in-java-8

Comment: @Flaom agree. But in my particular scenario, it occurred due to huge response body. I'll try to stream the response body, but in order to test that, I need a large response body