# How many bytes are needed to store a string of fixed length in java?

Tags: java, string, data-structures

What are the total number of bytes needed to store this in java?

String str = "1234"

Comment: That depends on what character encoding you use. If it's UTF-8, it would be 4 bytes with those specific characters, but it could be more with different characters. ASCII: 4 bytes, UTF-16: 8 bytes.

Comment: It also depends on the Java version, how much of the `String` representation you are considering, etc, etc.   (For example, a `String` object typically consists of 2 objects ... both of which have an object header.  But the size and type of the array is version dependent.)

Comment: @Jesper Java doesn't use UTF-8 to store strings in memory. They are stored in either UTF-16 or ISO-8859-1 (starting from Java 9).

Comment: @Olivier But it is not clear what navneet means with "store". Does he mean "store in memory" or "store in a file"?

Comment: @Jesper If it was "stored in file", the question would not be related to Java.

Comment: Yes ... but you can store a "string" in memory in lots of ways in Java.  `String` is only one possibility.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206851/how-much-memory-does-a-string-use-in-java-8.