# Minimum String memory usage in java 6

Tags: java-6

I read the article [string_memory_usage](https://www.javamex.com/tutorials/memory/string_memory_usage.shtml), then I have a question. What is 45 made of? 
I list what I know:

- for round up to the next multiple of 8 => 7 bytes
- 3 int field  =>  3 * 4 = 12bytes
- char array reference => 4byte
- string object header =>  8bytes
- 1 char array => at least 12 bytes for object header

Add all of the above is 43bytes.The remaining 2 is what?

Comment: Java 6 is old, the string memory usage change in Java 8, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31206851/how-much-memory-does-a-string-use-in-java-8

Comment: The link also contains the formula`(bytes) = 8 * (int) ((((no chars) * 2) + 45) / 8)`, I just want to know how did it get.