# How to remove trailling dots from pandas series?

Tags: python, pandas

How to remove trailing dots from pandas series?

## My attempt

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

pd.set_option('max_colwidth',1000)

s = pd.Series(["""Finally a transparant silicon case ^^ Thanks to my uncle :) #yay #Sony #Xperia #S #sonyexperias… http://instagram.com/p/YGEt5JC6JM/"""])


s.str.replace(r'(\w)\.+',r'\1',regex=True)
```

## My results

```
Finally a transparant silicon case ^^ Thanks to my uncle :) #yay #Sony #Xperia #S #sonyexperias… http://instagramcom/p/YGEt5JC6JM/


wanted:
Finally a transparant silicon case ^^ Thanks to my uncle :) #yay #Sony #Xperia #S #sonyexperia http://instagramcom/p/YGEt5JC6JM/
```

Comment: Those aren't multiple `.` characters, they're a single ellipsis character.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those aren't periods, they're the ellipsis character, which is Unicode character `\u2026`. See [How should I write three dots?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19997912/how-should-i-write-three-dots)

```
s.str.replace(r'(\w)\u2026+',r'\1',regex=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

Could you please try following, written as per shown samples.

```
pd.set_option('max_colwidth',1000)
s = pd.Series(["""Finally a transparant silicon case ^^ Thanks to my uncle :) #yay #Sony #Xperia #S #sonyexperias… http://instagram.com/p/YGEt5JC6JM/"""])
s.str.replace(r'…+',r'')
```

Answer (score 0):

As per suggestion of Barmar:

```py
s = pd.Series(["""Finally a transparant silicon case ^^ Thanks to my uncle :) #yay #Sony #Xperia #S #sonyexperias… http://instagram.com/p/YGEt5JC6JM/"""])


s.str.replace(r'(\w)…',r'\1',regex=True)

Gives:
Finally a transparant silicon case ^^ Thanks to my uncle :) #yay #Sony #Xperia #S #sonyexperias http://instagram.com/p/YGEt5JC6JM/
```