# How many bytes does a string contains?

Tags: java, string, unicode, utf-8

```
public class ClassToTestSnippets {

    private static ClassToTestSnippets ctts;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ctts = new ClassToTestSnippets();
        ctts.testThisMethod();
    }

    public void testThisMethod() {
        System.out.println("\u2014".length()); //answer is 1
    }
}
```

Above code prints 1. But `\u2014` is `E2 80 94` i.e. 3 bytes. How do I know how many bytes does a string contains?

Comment: This is like looking at a screenshot (not a file, just the displayed image) and asking how big the file is. The answer in both cases is that it depends how it's encoded...

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699071/what-is-the-javas-internal-represention-for-string-modified-utf-8-utf-16

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Depends. What encoding do you want to use?

```
System.out.println("äö".getBytes("UTF-8").length);
```

Prints 4, but if I change `UTF-8` to `ISO-8859-1` (for example), it'll print 2. Other encodings may print other values (try `UTF-32`).

Comment: This is not the number of bytes in the actual String object, though. It's the number of bytes in the UTF-8 representation of the string.

Answer (score 4):

Internally - it contains (number of chars) * 2 bytes, as each `char` in Java takes up two bytes (a normal character in Java is 16 bits unicode). The actual bytes are 0x20 and 0x14.

However, the length function returns the number of characters, not the number of bytes.

Comment: How do I store UTF-32? What happen then?

Comment: Internally it contains more than that. You're counting only the size of the internal `char[]` here, the size of the whole `String` is bigger.

Comment: You use two surrogate characters for any character that's above the 0xFFFF code point. See this [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html) from Oracle.

Comment: @Kayaman Indeed. But the number of additional bytes is constant and not dependent on the actual character data inside it.