# Meaning of getBytes() in java with strings

Tags: java, string, encoding

What is the meaning of the following?

```
String s = "some text here";
byte[] b = s.getBytes("UTF-8");
```

Does it mean, that the content in `b` is now encoded with UTF-8 
or
that we just got simple 0,1 Bytes from a string, which was encoded in UTF-8? Aren't all strings in java encoded in utf-16?
[What is the Java's internal represention for String? Modified UTF-8? UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699071/what-is-the-javas-internal-represention-for-string-modified-utf-8-utf-16)

Sometimes I see the following too:

```
byte ptext[] = myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); 
String value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
```

Answer (score 1):

`b` is the sequence of bytes that represents, in the UTF-8 encoding, the string `"some text here"`.  `String` uses UTF-16 internally.  Charsets *generally* are ways to convert between sequences of bytes and strings.

```
byte ptext[] = myString.getBytes("ISO-8859-1"); 
String value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
```

This looks like a hack taking advantage of two charsets having the same encoding in some specific cases, and is generally inadvisable.

Answer (score 1):

So a Java String is internally stored as `char[]`. Each `char` is [16 bits](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), and represents a Unicode character. When you need to obtain a `byte` array for that String, you need to tell the JVM how to encode those bytes. The `getBytes(Chatset)` method allows you to do that. The arg-less `getBytes()` method simply uses `Charset.defaultCharset()`. Depending on the encoding you choose (but you should choose the correct one) you may get a different count of bytes.

You can read more here: [Byte Encodings and Strings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/string.html).

Comment: Java strings are UTF-16 encoded.  Only _some_ Unicode characters can be encoded as a single `char` element in a string.  Others must be encoded as a _surrogate pair_.   Try this out for fun:  `System.out.println("".length());`