# Java String internal representation

Tags: java, string, encoding, utf-16

I understand that the internal representation of Java for String is UTF-16. [What is java string representation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699071/what-is-the-javas-internal-represention-for-string-modified-utf-8-utf-16)

Also, I know that in a UTF-16 String, each 'character' is encoded with one or two 16-bit code units.

However, when I debug the following java code

```
String hello = "Hello";
```

the variable hello is an array of 5 bytes 0x48, 0x101, 0x108, 0x108, 0x111
which is ASCII for "Hello".

How can this be?

Comment: How are you debugging this? It's just a char array of characters.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't the variable name you are seeing?

Comment: @Fildor 0x48 has the "H" char representation, not "h".

Comment: @MarounMaroun good point ...

Comment: [link](http://postimg.org/image/udpk662y5/)
This is a screenshot from my Intellij debugger.

Yes, Ferrybig - it is an array of characters

Comment: As you can see.. It's a char array..

Comment: Thanks for you quick response guys.
However, I still fail to understand - 
each of these chars seems to be one byte and not 2/4 as should be in UTF-16

Comment: How do you know that? The IntelliJ IDEA debugger does not show how many bytes are used to store a `char` value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a gcore dump of a mini java process with this code:

```
 class Hi {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        String hello = "Hello";
        try {
            Thread.sleep(60_000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

And did a `gcore` memory dump on Ubuntu. (usign `jps` to get the `pid` and passed that to gcore)

If found this: `48 65 6C 6C 6F` in the dump using a Hexeditor, so it is somewhere in the memory as ASCII.

But also `48 00 65 00 6C 00 6C` which is part of the `UTF-16` representation of the `String`

Comment: Yes, it's in ASCII (or rather UTF8) in the constant pool of the compiled .class file.

Comment: alright, so this answer,  with conjunction with @yole's comment above (Intellij debugger is somewhat now necessarily showing the size of each char) answers the question. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`String` internal representation is not specified, it's the implementation detail, so you cannot rely on it. It's very likely that in JDK-9 it will be changed to use double encoding (Latin-1 for strings which can be encoded in Latin-1, UTF-16 for other strings). See [JEP-254](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/254) for details. This feature is already integrated in OpenJDK master codebase, so if you are using Java-9 early access builds, you will have actually 5 bytes.