# Odd behaviour with StringBuilder, Java

Tags: java, output, stringbuilder

So I've been trying to print out some lines of "-" characters. Why does the following not work?:

```
StringBuilder horizonRule = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0 ; i < 12 ; i++) {
    horizonRule.append("─");
    System.out.println(horizonRule.toString());
}
```

The correct output is several lines like

```
─
──
───
────
```

and so on, but the incorrect output is

```
â??
â??â??
â??â??â??
```

I'm guessing the string is not being properly decoded by println or something

Comment: it works as you mentioned ? but Eclipse IDE ask me to save as UTF-8

Comment: Java uses UTF-8 as a default. What terminal or window are you using for your output? Is it a DOS window?

Comment: Java does *not* use UTF-8 as a default. Java uses the platform's default character set as a default.

Comment: Internally, to store Strings, etc, Java uses UTF-8. Output to a terminal or window will depend upon that terminal or window (which normally means the OS / platform)

Comment: @Stewart Internally, Java uses UTF-16, not UTF-8...

Comment: Blimey! Caught with my pants down! Thanks guys. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699071/what-is-the-javas-internal-represention-for-string-modified-utf-8-utf-16

Answer (score 3):

The string in your code is not a hyphen but a [UTF8 box drawing character](http://www.ltg.ed.ac.uk/~richard/utf-8.cgi?input=%E2%94%80&mode=char).

The terminal your application is printing to doesn't seem to expect any UTF8 content, so the issue is not inside your application.

Replace it with a real hyphen (`-`) or make sure the tool that displays the output supports UTF8.

Answer (score 1):

You say that the IDE wants to save as UTF-8. You then probably have saved it as UTF-8.

However your compiler is likely to compile in whatever encoding your system uses.

If you write your code as UTF-8, make sure to compile it with the same encoding:

```
javac -encoding utf8 MyClass.java
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code (I literally just copy'n'paste) using [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/), and it worked perfectly. So there's nothing wrong with the code. It will be your environment.

```
stewart$ bsh
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Djava.awt.headless=true -Dapple.awt.UIElement=true
BeanShell 2.0b4 - by Pat Niemeyer (pat@pat.net)
bsh % StringBuilder horizonRule = new StringBuilder();
bsh % for(int i=0; i<12; i++) {
horizonRule.append("─");
System.out.println(horizonRule.toString());
}
─
──
───
────
─────
──────
───────
────────
─────────
──────────
───────────
────────────
bsh %
```

Comment: This isn't an answer. What's wrong with his environment? Ask questions via comments until you can deduce the answer.

Comment: You want me to put the above output in a comment? Sheesh. At least admit that my contribution is helpful, by eliminating one possible source of the problem.

Comment: No, just the text before it would suffice.

Comment: Well, I considered I was being helpful by showing exactly what it was I tried. I'm sorry that happened to annoy you.

Comment: No annoyance here. I'm just offering observations. You seem a bit riled though.

Comment: The OP asked: "Why does the following not work?" My answer: "It does work." You: "That's not an answer." Me: "Rolls eyes." (As for, "Ask questions via comments until you can deduce the answer" - I'm not stopping you doing this. If you can do better than me, be my guest. Rather than just picking at someone's attempt to be helpful.)

Answer (score 0):

public class myTest1 {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder horizonRule = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 0 ; i <= 13 ; i++){
        horizonRule.append('_'); 
        System.out.println(horizonRule.toString());
    }
}
```

}

is correct;
maybe you use a different encoding ? clear env path