# Most efficient typecasting or converting long or int to 4 char string

Tags: java, string, integer, long-integer

My goal is to conserve space in my data store, which only accepts Strings.

Because a String in Java is a 16-bit array, I figure that in theory I should be able to convert my 8-byte long into a 4-char String, as both are represented by 8 bytes.  (To be clear, I am not interested in making my long integer human-readable in base 10, I want to store it in as short of a String as possible.)

However, almost all the literature I have found on this is about converting to the 8-bit byte type, not the type char.

I could encode as UTF8.  I am concerned this would mean I double the length of String, as each 8-bit byte is stored as a 16-bit char.  This would defeat my whole purpose for compacting my data into a 64-bit medium in the first place.

```
private static final Charset UTF8_CHARSET = Charset.forName("UTF-8");
new String(ByteBuffer.allocate(8).putLong(value).array(), UTF8_CHARSET);
```

Is my concern correct that I would be wasting space, and if so, is there a way to not waste space?

Comment: *"I am concerned this would mean I double the length of String, as each 8-bit byte is stored as a 16-bit char."* Your data store stores raw Java strings? What kind of data store is that? All of the ones I know of (DBs, for instance, or files) use their own formats for storing strings.

Comment: your *datastore* should store raw `byte[]` not `String`

Answer (score 2):

#### `char != int`

> Q: Are there any byte sequences that are not generated by a UTF? How
>   should I interpret them?
>
> A: **None of the UTFs can generate every arbitrary byte sequence.** For
>   example, in UTF-8 every byte of the form 110xxxxx2 must be followed
>   with a byte of the form 10xxxxxx2. A sequence such as <110xxxxx2
>   0xxxxxxx2> is illegal, and must never be generated. When faced with
>   this illegal byte sequence while transforming or interpreting, a UTF-8
>   conformant process must treat the first byte 110xxxxx2 as an illegal
>   termination error: for example, either signaling an error, filtering
>   the byte out, or representing the byte with a marker such as FFFD
>   (REPLACEMENT CHARACTER). In the latter two cases, it will continue
>   processing at the second byte 0xxxxxxx2.
>
> A conformant process must not interpret illegal or ill-formed byte
>   sequences as characters, however, it may take error recovery actions.
>   No conformant process  may use irregular byte sequences to encode
>   out-of-band information.

#### `String != byte[] && char != int`

Internally `String` objects are `Unicode` and encoded as `UTF-16` no matter what their source is.

> How is text represented in the Java platform?
>
> The Java programming language is based on the Unicode character set,
>   and several libraries implement the Unicode standard. The primitive
>   data type char in the Java programming language is an unsigned 16-bit
>   integer that can represent a Unicode code point in the range U+0000 to
>   U+FFFF, or the code units of UTF-16. The various types and classes in
>   the Java platform that represent character sequences - char[],
>   implementations of java.lang.CharSequence (such as the String class),
>   and implementations of java.text.CharacterIterator - are UTF-16
>   sequences.

#### `String` is internally represented by `UTF-16`

The character encodings like `UTF-8` are only for **interpreting** or **converting** to/from a `byte[]`.

Even if you write a custom [`CharsetProvider`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/nio/charset/spi/CharsetProvider.html) all that will do is encode/decode a `byte[]` **externally**, this will absolutely **not** change the fact that a [`String` is internally represented by `UTF-16`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699071/what-is-the-javas-internal-represention-for-string-modified-utf-8-utf-16), so what you want to do is kind of pointless.

#### Can't be done

[`Character` is actually a 32 bit number, the `Charset` is just an encoding of that 32 bit number. `UTF-8` can be 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes for example, and `UTF-16` is 2,4 bytes with a bit specifying if the next byte(s) is part of the same character or not.](http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html)

Comment: I agree that what I want to do is sort of pointless.  I am not the one forcing my data to type String.

Comment: OK, so I wrote some test code based on the idea char can be typecast to integer and back again.  I was hoping to go int[] --> char[] --> String --> char[] --> int[].  Not even int --> char --> int was reliable.  Ok, so the official answer, is "No, this cannot be done."  Thanks for the help.