# Which encoding does Java uses UTF-8 or UTF-16?

Tags: java, encoding, utf-8, default, utf-16

I've already read the following posts:

1. [What is the Java's internal represention for String? Modified UTF-8? UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699071/what-is-the-javas-internal-represention-for-string-modified-utf-8-utf-16)
2. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Now consider the code given below:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    printCharacterDetails("最");
}

public static void printCharacterDetails(String character){
    System.out.println("Unicode Value for "+character+"="+Integer.toHexString(character.codePointAt(0)));
    byte[] bytes = character.getBytes();
    System.out.println("The UTF-8 Character="+character+"  | Default: Number of Bytes="+bytes.length);
    String stringUTF16 = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
    System.out.println("The corresponding UTF-16 Character="+stringUTF16+"  | UTF-16: Number of Bytes="+stringUTF16.getBytes().length);
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
}
```

When I tried to debug the line `character.getBytes()` in the code above, the debugger took me into the `getBytes()` method of String class and then subsequently into the `static byte[] encode(char[] ca, int off, int len)` method of StringCoding class. The first line of the encode method (`String csn = Charset.defaultCharset().name();`) returned "UTF-8" as the default encoding during the debugging. I expected it to be "UTF-16".

The output of the program is:

Unicode Value for 最=6700
The UTF-8 Character=最  | Default: Number of Bytes=3

The corresponding UTF-16 Character=�  | UTF-16: Number of Bytes=6

When I converted it to UTF-16 explicitly in the program it took 6 bytes to represent the character. Shouldn't it use 2 or 4 bytes for UTF-16? Why 6 bytes were used?

Where am I going wrong in my understanding?
I use Ubuntu 14.04 and the locale command shows the following:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

Does this mean that JVM decides which encoding to use on the basis of underlying OS or does it use UTF-16 only?
Please help me understand the concept.

Comment: Don't confuse the default encoding of getBytes() with Java's internal encoding.

Comment: There is no way to access the internal representation of a String in Java. therefore you don't have to care about...

Comment: `character.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16)`, if you want the UTF-16 byte representation.

Comment: Thanks Andy ! It gives 4 bytes using your line of code.

Comment: Hi Alohci, what do we mean by "Java's internal encoding"? Can you please elaborate?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Characters are a graphical entity which is part of human culture. When a computer needs to handle text, it uses a *representation* of those characters in bytes. The exact representation used is called an **encoding**.

There are many encodings that can represent the same character - either through the Unicode character set, or through other character sets like the various ISO-8859 encodings, or the JIS X 0208.

Internally, Java uses UTF-16. This means that each character can be represented by one or two sequences of two bytes. The character you were using, 最, has the code point U+6700 which is represented in UTF-16 as the byte 0x67 and the byte 0x00.

That's the *internal* encoding. You can't see it unless you dump your memory and look at the bytes in the dumped image.

But the method `getBytes()` does *not* return this internal representation. Its documentation says:

> `public byte[] getBytes()`
>
> Encodes this `String` into a sequence of bytes
>   using the platform's default charset, storing the result into a new
>   byte array.

The "platform's default charset" is what your locale variables say it is. That is, `UTF-8`. So it takes the UTF-16 internal representation, and converts that into a different representation - UTF-8.

Note that

```
new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_16);
```

does **not** "convert it to UTF-16 explicitly" as you assumed it does. This string constructor takes a sequence of bytes, which is supposed to be in the encoding that you have given in the second argument, and converts it to the UTF-16 representation of whatever characters those bytes represent in that encoding.

But you have given it a sequence of bytes encoded in UTF-8, and told it to interpret that as UTF-16. This is wrong, and you do not get the character - or the bytes - that you expect.

You can't tell Java how to internally store strings. It always stores them as UTF-16. The constructor `String(byte[],Charset)` tells Java to create a UTF-16 string from an array of bytes that is supposed to be in the given character set. The method `getBytes(Charset)` tells Java to give you a sequence of bytes that represent the string in the given encoding (charset). And the method `getBytes()` without an argument does the same - but uses your platform's default character set for the conversion.

So you misunderstood what `getBytes()` gives you. It's *not* the internal representation. You can't get that directly. only `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16)` will give you that, and only because you know that `UTF-16` is the internal representation in Java. If a future version of Java decided to represent the characters in a different encoding, then `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16)` would not show you the internal representation.

**Edit:** in fact, Java 9 introduced just such a change in internal representation of strings, where, by default, strings whose characters all fall in the ISO-8859-1 range are internally represented in ISO-8859-1, whereas strings with at least one character outside that range are internally represented in UTF-16 as before. So indeed, `getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_16)` no longer returns the internal representation.

Comment: However, if I'm not mistaken, the fact that Java uses `UTF-16` for Char and String encoding is not an ***internal*** *implementation detail*, which can remain transparent to the developer, since some unicode code-points will occupy two positions in a String (as said below by RealSkeptic), and Java 9 (compact-string) hasn't changed anything from that point of view.

Comment: @Mabsten, the compact 8-bit represenation can't represent those characters anyway. But it's still an internal representation. If you use `charAt` it returns a 16 bit UTF-16 char, regardless of the internal representation.

Comment: Isn't there a naming error made by Java here? It uses `StandardCharsets` type to designate the _encoding_ of the bytes. Character set is _Unicode_ here, but what we really are setting is the **encoding**.

Answer (score 2):

As stated above, java uses UTF-16 as the encoding for character data.

To which it may be added that the set of representable characters is limited to a proper subset of the entire Unicode character set.  (I believe java restricts its character set to the Unicode BMP, all of which fit in two bytes of UTF-16.)

So the encoding applied is indeed UTF-16, but the character set to which it is applied is a proper subset of the entire Unicode character set, and this guarantees that Java always uses two bytes per token in its internal String encodings.

Comment: This is not correct for the current Java versions. In `String` object, Java represents characters which are outside of the BMP using surrogate pairs (which is part of the definition of UTF-16). So the `char` type indeed cannot represent a character outside of the BMP, but a Java `String` most certainly can.

Comment: Interesting.  And what happens upon a charAt() or getChars() invocation for such a String ?

Comment: When you write programs that need to be mindful of such characters, you use appropriate methods, such as `codePointAt(int)` instead of `charAt(int)`, `codePointCount(int,int)` instead of `length()` and so on.