# What type of character is this :  and how to handle it in java

Tags: java, xml, character-encoding, escaping, character

We want to send emails where customer name appears from a third party system. Those names now & then contains non english character. For example :

We form email request body in XML using java. Can someone please help what type of character is this and what type of encoding required to handle? If we use StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(string) method that causes request xml to become not parsable.

Comment: What do you mean? The output (with commons-text-1.8) parses correctly by `xmllint` when inserted into an XML.

Answer (score 1):

Those are some of the 143,859 characters defined in [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode#Versions).

The  , for example, is a "mathematical bold script capital j", 0x1D4D9 in hex, 120025 in decimal, `&#120025;` as an character entity.

For details on handling Unicode in Java, see

- [Java Unicode encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2533097/290085)
- [What is the Java's internal represention for String? Modified UTF-8? UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9699071/290085)
- [Which encoding does Java uses UTF-8 or UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39955169/290085)

Comment: And more generally: [*The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)*](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2003/10/08/the-absolute-minimum-every-software-developer-absolutely-positively-must-know-about-unicode-and-character-sets-no-excuses/) by Joel Spolsky.