# What is the difference in bytes of a number as a string and as an integer?

Tags: java, jvm

Let's say we have a `my_string = "123456"`

I do

```
my_string.getBytes()
```

and

```
new BigInteger(123456).toByteArray()
```

The resulting byte arrays are different for both these cases. Why is that so? Isn't "123456" same as 123456 other than the difference in data type?

Comment: As an `int`: 4 bytes, by definition. As a `String`: `log10(x)+1`, because the radix is different and the length is variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  Why would they be?  `"123456"` is a sequence of the ASCII character `1` (which is not represented as the number `1`, but as the number 49), followed by the number 2 (50), and so on.  `123456` as an `int` isn't even represented as a sequence of digits from 0-9, but it's stored as a number in *binary.*

Answer (score 3):

They are different because the `String` type is made up of unicode characters. The character `'2'` is *not at all* the same as the numeric value 2.

Comment: Upvoted for saying "Unicode" instead of "ASCII".  It's not the 1980s any more :-)

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you are asking about the total memory used to represent a number as a `String` versus a `byte[]`.

The `String` size will depend on the actual string representation used.  This depends on the JVM version; see [What is the Java's internal represention for String? Modified UTF-8? UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699071/what-is-the-javas-internal-represention-for-string-modified-utf-8-utf-16/9699138#9699138)

For Java 8 and earlier (with some caveats), the String consists of a `String` object with 1 `int` fields and 1 `reference` field. Assuming 64 bit references, that adds up to 8 bytes of header + 1 x 4 bytes + 1 x 8 bytes + 4 bytes of padding. Then add the `char[]` used to represent the characters: 12 bytes of header + 2 bytes per character.  This needs to be rounded *up* to a multiple of 8.

For Java 9 and later, the main object has the same size.  (There is an extra field ... but that fits into the "padding".)  The `char[]` is replaced by a `byte[]`, and since you are just storing ASCII decimal digits<sup>1</sup>, they will be encoded one character per byte.

In short, the *asymptotic* space usage is 1 byte per *decimal digit* for Java 9 or later and 2 bytes per *decimal digit* in Java 8 or earlier.

For the `byte[]` representation produce from a `BigInteger`, the represention consists of 12 bytes of header + 1 byte per `byte` ... rounded up to a multiple of 8.  The *asymptotic* size is 1 byte per `byte`.

In both cases there is also the size of the reference to the representation; i.e. another 8 bytes.

If you do the sums, the `byte[]` representation is more compact  than the `String` representation in all cases.  But `int` or `long` are significantly more compact that either of these representations in all cases.

---

<sup>1 - If you are not ... or if you are curious why I added this caveat ... read the Q&A at the link above!</sup>

Comment: Just to clarify: the optimization for Java 9+ is called "Compact Strings" and applies to strings which contain only ASCII characters. If you have the string "123č" then each char is represented as two bytes.

Comment: ... which does not apply to this question.

Comment: ...but can help to clarify the actual behavior and avoid drawing wrong conclusions in a different context.

Comment: This is already addressed: *"... and if you are just storing decimal digits, they will be encoded one character per byte."*   This question is about something very specific ... whether it saves space to store big numbers as strings versus byte arrays.  I disagree that my answer needs an edit to deal with Java 9+ string optimization.  Feel free to write your own answer.