# Understanding encoding in character streams

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding, stream

I'm trying to understand how encodings are applied by character streams in Java.   For the discussion let's use the following code example:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {    
    byte[] utf8Input = new byte[] { (byte) 0xc3, (byte) 0xb6 }; // 'ö'
    ByteArrayOutputStream utf160Out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    InputStreamReader is = new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(utf8Input), StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // [
    OutputStreamWriter os = new OutputStreamWriter(utf160Out, StandardCharsets.UTF_16);

    int len;
    while ((len = is.read()) != -1) {
      os.write(len);
    }
    os.close();
  }
```

The program reads the UTF-8 encoded character 'ö' from the byte array *utf8Input* and writes it UTF-16 encoded to *utf160Out*. In particular, the ByteArrayInputStream on *utf8Input* just streams the bytes 'as-is' and the InputStreamReader subsequently decodes the read input with an UTF-8 decoder. Dumping the result of the *len* variable yields '0xf6' which represents the Unicode code point for 'ö'. The OutputStreamWriter writes using UTF-16 encoding without having any knowledge about the input encoding.

How does the OutputStreamWriter know the input encoding (here: UTF-8)? Is there an internal representation that is assumed which is also mapped to by an InputStreamReader? So basically, we are saying then: Read this input, it is UTF-8 encoded and decode it to our internal encoding **X**. An OutputStreamWriter is given the target encoding and expects the input to be encoded with **X**. Is this correct? If so, what is the internal encoding? UTF-16 as mentioned in [What is the Java's internal represention for String? Modified UTF-8? UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699071/what-is-the-javas-internal-represention-for-string-modified-utf-8-utf-16)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`read()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Reader.html#read--) method has returned a Java `char` value, which is an unsigned 2-byte binary number (0-65535).

The actual return type is `int` (signed 4-byte binary number) to allow for a special `-1` value meaning end-of-stream.

A Java `char` is a UTF-16 encoded Unicode character. This means that all characters from the [Basic Multilingual Plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(Unicode)#Basic_Multilingual_Plane) will appear unencoded, i.e. the `char` value is the Unicode value.