# How to get 5 characters of any encoding Java-string?

Tags: java, string, encoding, formatting, codepoint

#### Problem

How can I get only 5 characters of the string if sometimes encoding looks like "UTF-8", "UTF-16" and "ASCII"?

Note: some of the tests input has emoji.

#### Code

```
    public String truncate(String input) {
        if (input.codePointCount(0, input.length()) > 5)
        {
            return input.substring(0, input.offsetByCodePoints(0, 5));
        }

        return input;
    }
```

#### For example:

Input: `Bärteppich`

Expected Output: `BГ¤rte` also means `Bärte`

Actual Output: `BГ¤rt`

Input: `brühe`

Expected Output: `brГјhe` also means `brühe`

Actual Output: `brГјh`

Comment: Why do you **intentionally** want to get [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) out of Strings? `BГ¤rte` doesn't "also mean" `Bärte`, it means you don't handle encoding correctly.

Comment: I assume the odd rendering is due to print and and not a corrupt String. Does char by char print of input and output look to have expected values? eg try adding this to the before and after `System.out.println("input "+Arrays.toString(input.toCharArray()));`

Comment: @DuncG even the question implies that they're reading different encodings but treating them as the same (possibly the platform default), which is the whole root of their problem.

Comment: @Kayaman It looks likely yes, but just because the chars don't print to terminal does not imply the input is corrupt which is why I asked. eg its possible to read Japanese database text into UK base machines as String and write 100% safely, but there was no way I could print that text to terminal on my machine as it was writing as it would show as garbled text in machine with ASCII default.

Comment: @DuncG I know. I also know from the dozens of encoding related questions I've gone through and tried to answer, that people just don't understand encoding. They refuse to accept that their input data is broken, and code should be fixed when it's read in, instead they want hacky code to work on the broken data.

Answer (score 0):

First, for all purposes a Java `String` is always UTF-16, although since Java 9 it may be something else *internally*.

To achieve what you want ("Get only the first five characters from the input String!"), it should look like this:

```
public String truncate( String input ) 
{
    var retValue = (input != null) && (input.length() > 5)
        ? input.substring( 0, 5 )
        : input;

        return retValue;
}
```

There should be no need to play around with codepoints for this particular task.

Unfortunately, this is not fully correct.

It works for the String `s = "Dies ist ein langer String";`.

It does not work for `s = "12345678";`.

Unfortunately, `String.offsetByCodePoints()` is of no help here; when using the original code from the question, like this:

```
public String truncate( String input ) 
{
    int x = 5;
    if( input.codePointCount( 0, input.length() ) > 5 )
    {
        return input.substring( 0, input.offsetByCodePoints( 0, x ) );
    }

    return input;
}
```

the correct value for `x` depends on the contents of the String.

That's because  counts for two codepoints, while  is just one – and both are more than one `char`.

So this one failed, too:

```
public String truncate( String input ) 
{
    var retValue = input;
    if( input.codePointCount( 0, input.length() ) > 5 )
    {
        int [] codepoints = input.codePoints().limit( 5 ).toArray();
        retValue = new String( codepoints, 0, 5 );
    }
    return retValue;
}
```

And here I am stuck …

Comment: It's UTF-16 only [pre-Java9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699071/what-is-the-javas-internal-represention-for-string-modified-utf-8-utf-16).

Comment: @Kayaman: You are right, but for the purpose of this question, it is transparent whether it is UTF-16 or UTF-8 or ISO-8859-1 – not to mention that the conversion from one the other is transparent, too.

Comment: @Kayaman I disagree.  The String class, like every good OO class, encapsulates its state, so internal representation is irrelevant.  As far as any program is concerned, a String is comprised of UTF-16 `char` values, or 32-bit Unicode codepoints.

Comment: @Kayaman Ah, I overlooked that tquadrat wrote that internally it’s UTF-16 until you pointed that out.  Fair enough.