# Clarification on how character encodings work

Tags: java, unicode, character-encoding, ascii

I am writing a program to get the "sum" of a word, based on letters (i.e. "abc" = a+b+c = 1+2+3 = 6). I am using the method of `total += (int) char - 'a' + 1` (in Java). The program is to be case insensitive ('A' = 'a'), so first I want to convert the char to lowercase if necessary. I have written

```
if (char < 'a') {char += 32;}
```

which is correct in UTF-16 and ASCII, but not UTF-8.

My question is, if I were to ship this code, how does encoding work past compiling? If the user is using UTF-8, will the program fail (so it's better to use `Character.toLowerCase()`), or since the program is in Java, any characters in the program will be the program's encoding, hence it works?

In case it isn't clear, I have no idea what I'm talking about, so some general info about how the encoding works would be great too.

Comment: Java uses UTF-16 by default, but you can set the string's charset in the constructor. You can use String.toLowerCase to make it case-insensitive. Here is a table of standard ASCII character values: http://www.asciitable.com/ This is basically what you want to use.

Comment: You can't set the charset **of the String**, it is UTF-16. You can state the charset of the byte array you're using to initializd the String; this tells the runtime how to convert into UTF-16.

Comment: Why not use an existing [hash function](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) rather than invent your own? [`String::hashCode`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) returns an `int`.

Comment: @BasilBorque - that's not what he's trying to do. He seems to want to replace specific letters by specific values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Java String is always encoded in UTF-16; input and output are converted as necessary.

This, however, can be better written:

```
 if (char < 'a') {char += 32;}
```

as

```
 if (ch >= 'A' && ch <= 'Z')
    ch += ('a' - 'A');
```

Reason:

1. Checking for the expected range is just more cautious
2. You do not need to 'know' that the distance between lower-case alphabetics and upper-case alphabetics is 32.

Also, 'char' is a keyword in Java.

This of course only works for letters in the unaccented USA/UK alphabet.

However, I would suggest you use (as you yourself stated)  'toLowerCase()' since that's what it's there for - to relieve you of details.

Comment: I do not actually use `char` as the name, it's just a placeholder for my complicated variable name

Comment: Changing to lower case by subtraction works for A-Z, but not generally. If you want to support letters beyond A-Z, you need to use a case mapping function.

Comment: And then you have to worry about letters that have more than one lower-case representation: Σ maps to either σ or ς.

Comment: While there were no API changes, since Java 9 it has not been true that _"A Java String is always encoded in UTF-16"_. See JEP 400 and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9699138/2985643) to the question _"What is the Java's internal represention for String? Modified UTF-8? UTF-16?"_.