# Decode Korean String from Bytes in Java

Tags: java, string, utf-8, cjk

I ran into struggles converting a byte array korean chars in Java.
Wikipedia states that somehow 3 bytes are beeing used for each char, but not all bits are taken into account.

Is there a simple way of converting this very special...format? I don't want to write loops and counters keeping track of bits and bytes, as it would get messy and I can't imagine that there is no simple solution. A native java lib would be perfect, or maybe someone figured some smart bitshift logic out.

UPDATE 2:
A working solution has been posted by @DavidConrad below, I was wrong assuming it is UTF-8 encoded.

UPDATE:

These bytes

```
[91, -80, -8, -69, -25, 93, 32, -64, -78, -80, -18, -73, -50]
```

should output this:

```
[공사] 율곡로
```

But using

```
new String(shortStrBytes,"UTF8"); // or
new String(shortStrBytes,StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

turns them to this:

```
[����] �����
The returned string has 50% more chars
```

Comment: What's wrong with `new String(koreanBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`?

Comment: It does not work, it ends up with 50% more chars than there should be also all chars are replaced by rectangles. I think it used 3 bytes per char and that is why it would be 50% longer using  new String(koreanBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)

Comment: It doesn't sound like your data is actually UTF-8. You say "converting a byte array to UTF_8 korean chars" but what are you converting FROM? Also, chars are not UTF-8, they are UTF-16. Java always uses UTF-16 to represent Unicode internally.

Comment: @DavidConrad It's no longer the case that _"Java always uses UTF-16 to represent Unicode internally"_. See [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9699138/2985643) to the question "[What is the Java's internal representation for String? Modified UTF-8? UTF-16?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9699071/2985643)".

Comment: @skomisa Yes, I know that it can store it as Latin1 internally but that's an implementation detail that isn't really visible. If you access the chars, you still get 16-bit values back.

Comment: @DavidConrad a colleague told me that using UTF-8 in C# would decode it correctly. I did not verify it and trying to do the same in Java fails. It is binary data taken from a TPEG binary stream.

Comment: @DavidConrad Huh??? You wrote _"Java always uses UTF-16 to represent Unicode internally"_ and then wrote _"I know that it can store it as Latin1 internally"_.

Comment: @skomisa Yes, I shouldn't have said that. You're right. But from the user's point of view, you can only get chars (UTF-16) or ints (Unicode code points). You can never see the Latin1 code points. It's purely an optimization to save space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you added the bytes to the question, I have done a little research and some experimenting, and I believe that the text you have is encoded as [EUC-KR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Unix_Code#EUC-KR). I got the expected Korean characters when interpreting them as that encoding.

```
// convert bytes to a Java String
byte[] data = {91, -80, -8, -69, -25, 93, 32, -64, -78, -80, -18, -73, -50};
String str = new String(data, "EUC-KR");

// now convert String to UTF-8 bytes
byte[] utf8 = str.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
System.out.println(HexFormat.ofDelimiter(" ").formatHex(utf8));
```

This prints the following hexadecimal values:

> 5b ea b3 b5 ec 82 ac 5d 20 ec 9c a8 ea b3 a1 eb a1 9c

Which is the proper UTF-8 encoding of those Korean characters and, with a terminal that supported them, printing the string should display them properly, too.

Comment: wow thank you very much, it works perfectly and is a clean and native solution. I did not know there existed a "EUC-KR" format. Where did you find the information? I also did some research, but obviously I didn´t search at the right places.

Comment: @Yesyoor I searched for encodings for Korean, and then I tried a few of them in Java. "ISO-2022-KR" didn't give good results; "EUC-KR" did. Those were the first two (other than Unicode) that I found, and the only ones I tried. You can [accept my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it.

Comment: oh yes I meant to accept the answer but only upvoted it :D has been done now, thanks again for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `StandardCharsets.UTF_8`.
Converting from `String` to `byte[]` and vice versa:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class Translater {

    public static String translateBytesToString(byte[] b) {
      return new String(b, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    public static byte[] translateStringToBytes(String s) {
      return s.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final String STRING = "[공사] 율곡로";
        final byte[] BYTES = {91, -22, -77, -75, -20, -126, -84, 93, 32, -20, -100, -88, -22, -77, -95, -21, -95, -100};
    
        String s = translateBytesToString(BYTES);
        byte[] b = translateStringToBytes(STRING);
    
        System.out.println("String: " + translateBytesToString(BYTES));
        System.out.print("Bytes: ");
        for (int i=0; i<b.length; i++)
           System.out.print(b[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: hey thanks, I updated my question and added the original bytes. They are different than yours, maybe I was wrong that UTF-8 is used, but it seems to have worked in C# using UTF_8. It does not work for Java though. Maybe the infomation given about C# ewas incorrect as a colleague tried it out there.

Comment: Please take a look at the bytes I added to the question, your array is 18 bytes long, my array is 13 bytes long. Maybe this is giving a hint? I think the bytes are double encoded as described in Wikipedia. I wonder if there is a lib or native lib that can handle it.

Comment: The problem is, the text is not actually UTF-8.