# Japanese file name not showing properly in IE Using java

Tags: java

When i download the file (`pdf`/`xls`/`text`) file from portal, the file name is not showing properly in `IE` and working fine in other browsers

```
if(((String) requestKeys.getSessionAttribute(EnumParameterNames.USER_AGENT)).contains("MSIE")){
    fileName = URLEncoder.encode(fileName, "UTF-8"); // it results filename mL_úPDF_20150210185915.pdf  
} else {
    fileName = "=?UTF-8?B?" + new String(Base64.encodeBase64(fileName.getBytes("UTF-8")), "UTF-8") + "?="; // working fine for all browsers 
}
```

I have used Content-Disposition also and but getting same error

```
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename="+fileName);
```

please suggest and thanks for the help!

Comment: [Don't support IE](https://paydirtapp.com/blog/we-dont-support-ie/)

Comment: you problem is IE and you file encoding.

Comment: I think m0skit0 is correct on this one. Even if it was not IE it is a bad practice to alter your code just to satisfy the needs of a single one. UTF-8 supports Japanese unless some pretty exotic characters don't show up. If one sticks to the "basics" UTF-16 is used as a fixed length UTF-8-like encoding in such cases. Btw when posting such questions relating to a specific software product one should not forget to mention which version is used! Also see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4655335/1559401

Comment: I am using java 1.6v and WAS server

Answer (score 0):

Try using UTF-16LE encoding instead of UTF-8. This should resolve your issue.

Comment: Hi Rahul, i have tried with UTF-16LE but not resolved my issue.

Comment: Hi user3714194, since this is happening only on IE, u can try uninstalling and then re-installing the Japanese language pack from control panel>region and language.